# numbering characters in a string

Tags: r, string

I want to number the letters in a large dataset. Some letters occur multiple times and are numbered ("A1", "A2"), others also occur multiple times but are not numbered. There are also letters that occur only once... but maybe it's easier to look at the example data below.

The numbers in df$nr are the desired result. How can I get df$nr from df$word and df$letter ?

```
df <-tibble(word=c(rep("Amamam", 17), rep("Bobob", 14)),
            letter=c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "m", "m", "m", "a", "a", "m", "m", "a", "a", "m", "m",
                     "B1", "B1", "B2", "B2", "B3", "B3", "o", "b", "b", "b", "o", "o", "o", "b"),
            nr=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6,
                 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5) )
```

Comment: How exactly are the letters numbered?

Comment: do you really just want to know the position every time the sequence changes? for each word?

Comment: @tmfmnk The numbers behind the letters are not relevant, sorry. I should have removed them from the example.

Comment: @Mike Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can group by 'word', remove the numeric part from the 'letter' column, convert to run-length-id (`rleid` from `data.table`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
df1 <- df %>% 
        group_by(word) %>%
        mutate(nr1 = rleid(str_remove(letter, "\\d+")))

all.equal(df1$nr, df1$nr1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast, thanks. The second "m" in "Amamam" needs to get a 4 and the third "m" a 6, though.

Comment: @Rumpi  I did updated that part and tested with your desired output.  It is the same

Comment: Thanks, that saved me!